How to Accurately Check Cycle Time for CAN Messages on Multiple Buses in CAPL using CANoe?
I'm currently working on a CAN network simulation using CANoe, and I am writing CAPL scripts to monitor the cycle time of CAN messages. My setup involves multiple CAN buses that share the same message names and IDs.
Due to this shared setup, I'm encountering an issue where the calculated cycle time for these messages is much lower than specified in the database.
For instance, a message with a specified cycle time of 5 ms is appearing with an average cycle time of 2.5 ms because it exists on two different buses.
I tried to use the ChkStart_MsgRelCycleTimeViolation function to monitor the cycle time violations, but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly in the context of multiple buses.
How can I modify my CAPL script to accurately calculate and monitor the cycle time for messages that are present on multiple buses, ensuring the cycle time matches the specified value in the database?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Can you post a code example?

My suggestion would be instead of having your CAPL node assigned to multiple buses (making it a gateway node), use separate nodes for each bus. That way, the CAPL inside only has access to messages on its assigned bus. You could potentially even use the same CAPL file, just make them separate nodes on each bus.
